# Error Setting Default Scaffolder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a solution that uses NuGet to manage packages, and I also use the Package Manager Console for Entity Framework Migrations.  Everything has worked fine for around a year.

This morning I removed a few projects from the solution as part of a reorganization.  Now when I open the Package Manager Console, I am greeted with the error message

```
Set-DefaultScaffolder : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At E:\Dev\survey\packages\T4Scaffolding.Core.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:50 char:9
+         Set-DefaultScaffolder -Name CustomTemplate -Scaffolder 
T4Scaffolding.Cus ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-DefaultScaffolder], NullR 
   eferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.SetDefaultScaffolderCmdlet
```

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Visual Studio 2012 SP2 a day or so after posting this issue, and it resolved itself.

Unsure whether SP2 fixed the underlying issue or just reset something, but either way the problem is resolved.